# Conflict between Org Based (normal) deployment and DX deployment

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-development

We are following two ways for code deployment:

1. Org Deployment model Using Gearset (building package and deploying using quickdeploy option).
2. Salesforce DX - ( 20-30% dev groups are using this approach).

Now: Under option 1 we are ready with our built and package is ready in Prod for quick deploy but there is a DX deployment in production before us. 
My question is - will DX deployment will remove my quick deploy build available in Production? Please help as I am new in Salesforce DX.

Thanks.

Build is created for the deployment in PROD via Org Deployment flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot quick deploy after performing another deployment, nor should you in any case.

From [Monitor Deployments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=deploy_monitoring.htm&type=5) in Salesforce Help:

> If you perform a deployment after a validation, whether through Quick Deploy, a package installation, or a regular deployment, all validations no longer qualify for quick deployment. Revalidate the set of components to quick-deploy.

Your Apex test passes from a validation run are no longer meaningful after you perform another deploy because the target environment has changed. You need to revalidate to determine that your deployment still works when integrated with the changed target environment.